# How to add and subtract in python

Tags: python, addition, subtraction

So I am making a statcalc and everything is working except adding. When I select the option to add it just skips it and says select an option. I was wondering what's wrong with it?

```
numberstoadd = input("What is the first number you want to add? ")
numbertoadd = input("What do you want to add to it? ")
sum = numbertoadd + numberstoadd
print sum
```

Comment: Show us the selection code, not the addition.

Comment: Edit it into the question, with the indentation you're using in the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn your input `string`s into `int`s. Like this:

```
number_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number you want to add? "))
number_2 = int(raw_input("What do you want to add to it? "))
sum = number_1 + number_2
print sum
```

Comment: Python 2 `print` statements, so this isn't it.

Comment: @user2357112 `input` definitely still works in python2, but you're right it should be using `raw_input`.

Comment: `input` isn't the best of options, but if you type in an int, `input` will give you an int. The addition code should work as long as the input is well-formed. It should still be changed, but it's not the cause of the questioner's problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, `input` would `eval` the typed text and return an integer, whereas under Python 3 `input` just returns a `string` containing the typed text (equivalent to `raw_input` in Python 2).

See this link for other changes between Python version 2.x & 3.x

http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score -1):

```
print("Welcome to fizz buzz")
num1=input("Choose a number from 1 to 100")
if num1 is >= 50:
 print("hello")
else:
 print("good bye")
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all. Try to be more descriptive at least.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

Sample Input 0

2

1 3

10 100

Sample Output 0

-2

-90

Given a two integers print the difference of two integers.

*Hint: Try to implement without using '-' operator.