# Issues subtracting numbers in python

Tags: python, subtraction

I am having trouble subtracting the `creditsLeft = creditsDegree – creditsTaken`.
I'm not sure how to setup the calculation.

```
studentName = input('Enter student name.')
studentDegree = input('Enter degree name.')
creditsDegree = int(input('Enter the number of credits required for the degree.'))
creditsTaken = int(input('Enter the number of credits taken for the degree.'))
remaining = (Taken - Degree)
print('The student\'s name is', studentName)
print('The degree name is', studentDegree)
print('The number required for the degree is', creditsDegree)
print('The number of credits taken so far is', creditsTaken)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22002652/1514049) help at all? You should just be able to do `creditsLeft = creditsDegree – creditsTaken` right after you get your last input for `creditsTaken`...

Comment: yes it worked. I was doing something else but it works now.